# Does std::thread library in C++ support nested threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I want to create nested threads in C++ using `std::thread` library like this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void innerfunc(int inp)
{
    cout << inp << endl;
}
void outerfunc(int inp)
{
    thread * threads = new thread[inp];
    for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++)
        threads[i] = thread(innerfunc, i);
    for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++)
        threads[i].join();
    delete[] threads;
}
int main()
{
     int inp = 0;
     thread t1 = thread(outerfunc,2);
     thread t2 = thread(outerfunc,3);
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
}
```

Can I do this safely? I am worried whether `join()` works correctly.

Comment: Unrelated, I'd start by putting that mysteriously-included but-never-used `<vector>` to good use, rather than managing dynamic allocation yourself.

Comment: What does "safe" mean? How is "working correctly" different from just "working"?

Comment: I don't comprehend what you mean by "nested threads" here - what is nested?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really such a thing as "nested" or "children" threads in C++, the OS models don't immediately map to C++. The model for C++ is more accurately described along the lines of [threads of execution being associated with `thread` objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

From the linked cppreference;

> The class thread represents a single thread of execution.

`thread` objects can be moved (`std::move`) around as required; it really is more an issue of ownership and who needs to `join()` the `thread` object before it goes out of scope.

In answer to the questions;

> Can I do this safely?

Yes. Threads of execution (and their associated `thread` objects) can be created in "nested" threads and be successfully executed.

> I am worried whether `join()` works correctly.

Yes it will. This is related to the "ownership" of the thread. So long as the thread of execution is joined before the `thread` object goes out of scope, it will work as you expect.

---

On a side note; I'm sure the `innerfunc` is for demonstration only, but `cout` will probably not synchronize as expected. The output will be "garbled".

Comment: I don't think "children threads" is a thing. There is no relationship among threads as far as the C++ threading model is concerned. All threads are equal, any one thread can join any other thread.

Comment: Correct, but the OP worded is as "nested" threads, implying his internal logic is ordering these. I'll add some notes on that.

Comment: Sure, of course, the whole problem here is that the OP is suffering from unwarrented misconceptions. I guess my point was that an answer should probably start *there* rather than by playing by the OP's rules and exploring non-existing concepts, if that makes sense.

Comment: Correct. I'll start the answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works perfectly! Just add a lock for all the 'cout' statements. Otherwise, the values will get garbled.

```
mutex m;

void innerfunc(int inp)
{
    m.lock();
    cout <<"Innerfunc triggered " << inp << endl;
    m.unlock();
}

void outerfunc(int inp)
{
    m.lock();
    cout <<"Outerfunc triggered " << inp << endl;
    m.unlock();
    thread * threads = new thread[inp];
    for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++)
        threads[i] = thread(innerfunc, i);
    for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++)
        threads[i].join();
    delete[] threads;
}
```